# Need to prove continuity for Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm in real analysis class and I have a question that reads as follows:

```
prove that x^10000 + x^1000 - 1 = 0 has a solution with 0 < x < 1.
```

I'm thinking I can use the intermediate value theorem and state that f(0) = -1, and f(1) = 1 and by IVT, there must be a solution with 0 < x < 1.

My problem is that I'm unsure if I need too prove it is continuous since the IVT depends on continuity. If so, I'm not sure how to prove continuity.

Comment: Did you prove that differentiable functions are continuous? Polynomials are infinitely differentiable, hence continuous. And the sum of continuous functions is again continuous.

Comment: Indeed, you have to prove continuity. Since $x^a$ is continuos for every $a\ge 0$ and sum of continuos functions is continuos, you are done. If you want to prove those properties from first principle, try to work it out using definitions of continuity and properties of limit

Comment: @William I dont think we have gone into differentiation at all in this class so I'm assuming I couldn't use that as an argument. I'll have to double check with the professor though

Comment: @Ant, thanks! I'll try to work it out with the limit properties and continuity. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* apply the Intermediate Value Theorem here, since the function f(x) = x^10000 + x^1000 - 1 is continuous on [0, 1]. To show continuity, note that:

1. f is defined everywhere on [0, 1] since the exponential expressions are defined for all x in this interval
2. The limit of f(x) as x approaches a in [0, 1] exists and equals f(a), since the exponential function is continuous

Therefore, f is continuous on [0, 1], and IVT applies. Since f(0) = -1 and f(1) = 1, there must exist a c in (0, 1) such that f(c) = 0. Thus, we have shown that x^10000 + x^1000 - 1 = 0 has a solution with 0 < x < 1, as desired.

Alternatively, we could prove this using integration and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, or using a contradiction argument with an appropriate lemma. All three are valid approaches to solving this problem.